# Open a specific tab/view when user receives a push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to do something like Twitter app: when someone write me I receive the push notification; if I "slide on the notification" the app starts, but not in the normal stream, it starts in a specific view with the tweet that someone wrote me!

In my app I have something like an RSS reader, and the push notification arrives when there is a new news.
So, I want to open the "single news view", and not the main view (that's happening now).

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do two things.

One is to check the `launchOptions` dictionary of the `UIApplicationDelegate` method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to see if the app was launched via a user clicking on a notification. If so, then in that method you can push the appropriate view controller onto the stack, just as you would normally with in-app usage.

If the app is already open, but in the background then the same theory applies but instead use the `UIApplicationDelegate` method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) for information on handling incoming notifications.

Comment: That's all well and good, but it looks like the view hierarchy hasn't loaded yet. What's the best way to handle that?

Comment: @elsurudo I'm a bit late but you could handle it by using JLRoutes which allows you to route from anywhere to any view in your app. Please see: https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes

Comment: Note that it's usually bad practice to force navigation when the app is in foreground. The user can't see that he received a notification at that point, and yet the page suddenly changes without his consent, its very confusing, and if he was doing "something important" somewhere else, then it's flat out irritating.

That being said, that very same method is called if the user taps on the notification, so you could just check the UIApplicationState before navigating away

Comment: I can receive the notification, but I do not receive its userInfo. Instead I only receive:

`▿ Optional<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("NotificationIdentifier")
        - value : "NotificationIdentifier"
      - value : 0F99DF81-C721-4A56-850A-13CF74A85547`
How can I get to the actual content of the notification?