# iOS Local Notification Opens Specific Tab?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uilocalnotification

I am building an app with a quote of the day as my Third tab in the tab controller.  I would like the option of Local Notifications to let the user know at times they schedule that there is a new quote.  I would also like to have the app open straight to the third tab when the notification is clicked, but I'm not sure how to do this last part.  I have looked at [Open a specific tab/view when user receives a push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734338/open-a-specific-tab-view-when-user-receives-a-push-notification) but the accepted answer really didn't have any details as to how to do it.  The local notifications are set up already in code, just need to know what to put in the code for the notification or the appdelegate itself to have it open to third tab.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```